# Organizing elements by percentage of width HTML, CSS

Tags: css, html

Suppose I want to organize 4 "divs" in the header to fit horizontally with this simplified code. Now this may seem to be an overly simple question, but my browser even fully windowed only displays three in one horizontal row as opposed to 4. Any ideas why would be appreciated since the width is 25%.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<style>
.division{
  width:25%;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  border-style: ridge;
}
</style>
<body>
<header>
<div  class = "division"> 1 </div>
<div  class = "division"> 2 </div>
<div  class = "division"> 3 </div>
<div  class = "division"> 4 </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The border size is not counted as part of the width so if you add in the borders that makes more than 100% and   there is only space for three. You can try setting `box-sizing: border-box` so that the border is included in the width of the box.

Comment: @CharlieFish that clearly 4 should be in one row but there are 3...

Comment: There are some good explanations of box sizing at the duplicate linked by Xufox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the border takes space as well! So you will end up with more than 100%. Take a look at the box model of CSS.

[image]

### Box-Sizing

To change the box model you can add the `box-sizing` property to your `division` class, for example:

`box-sizing:border-box;`

This will change the behavior of the boxes. The border and the padding is part of the width now.

### Calculation

Alternatively you could subtract the `border-width` ( * 2 ) from the width, for a `border-width` of 1px it could look like this:

`width:calc(25% - 2px);`